# Wayland on top of X11

Tags: linux, window-manager

There is [XWayland](http://wayland.freedesktop.org/xserver.html) to emulate [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) on top of [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_%28display_server_protocol%29).

I want the reverse - being able to experiment with Wayland without reconfiguring the system for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can run Weston inside X11. It's not the same because it's like having a different desktop environment inside a X11 window but you can use it to try the Wayland backends for apps.

Comment: `Weston - reference implementation of a wayland compositor` -> So "compositor" for Wayland is like "server" for X11?

Comment: No, Wayland has only one server. Weston it's like Compiz or KWin (KDE compositor). The fact is that apps running on Weston are using Wayland and you can run Weston in a X11 session.